# How to append to __preinit_array_start on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, initialization

On Linux with GCC if I define

```
__attribute__((constructor)) static void myfunc(void) {}
```

, then the address of `myfunc` will be appended to `__init_array_start` in the `.ctors` section. But how can I append a function pointer to `__preinit_array_start`?

Is `__preinit_array_start` relevant in a statically linked binary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As there's no `__attribute__((preconstructor))`, you can just mush the code into the relevant section using some section attributes e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int v;
int w;
int x;

__attribute__((constructor)) static void
foo(void)
{
    printf("Foo %d %d %d\n", v, w, x);
}

static void
bar(void)
{
    v = 3;
}

static void
bar1(void)
{
    w = 2;
}

static void
bar2(void)
{
    x = 1;
}

__attribute__((section(".preinit_array"))) static void (*y[])(void) = { &bar, &bar1, &bar2 };

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
}
```

File dumped into `foo.c`, compiled using: `gcc -o foo foo.c`, and then run yields an output of:

```
Foo 3 2 1
Hello World
```

File compiled using `gcc -static -o foo foo.c`, and then run yields the same output, so it does appear to work with statically linked binaries.

It will **not** work with `.so` files, though; the linker complains with:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccI0lMgd.o: .preinit_array section is not allowed in DSO
/usr/bin/ld: failed to set dynamic section sizes: Nonrepresentable section on output
```

I'd be inclined to avoid it, as code run in that section precedes all other initialization routines. If you're trying to perform some 'this is supposed to run first' initialization, then it's really not a good idea - you're just fighting a race condition which should be solved by some other mechanism.

Comment: Do you have any information about the intended purpose of `__preinit_array_start`? It looks like terribly underdocumented.

Comment: The only references that explain it in any real detail is the [System V ABI](http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/latest/ch5.dynamic.html#init_fini). It's for self-contained initialization code for an executable. The code operates at the earliest point of startup possible (i.e. after everything's been mapped in, but before constructors are invoked). There's no guarantee that any library code would work properly in this situation e.g. const objects would not be available at this point.