# Why do program-level constructors get called by `__libc_csu_init` but destructors don't get called by `__libc_csu_fini`?

Tags: c++, assembly, gdb, glibc, libc

Here's a simple program:

```cpp
void __attribute__ ((constructor)) dumb_constructor(){}

void __attribute__ ((destructor)) dumb_destructor(){}

int main() {}
```

I compile it with the following flags:

```
g++ -O0 -fverbose-asm -no-pie -g -o main main.cpp
```

I check with `gdb` that `__libc_csu_init` is calling the function I tagged w/ constructor:

```
Breakpoint 1, dumb_constructor () at main.cpp:1
1   void __attribute__ ((constructor)) dumb_constructor(){}
(gdb) bt
#0  dumb_constructor () at main.cpp:1
#1  0x000000000040116d in __libc_csu_init ()
#2  0x00007ffff7abcfb0 in __libc_start_main () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#3  0x000000000040104e in _start ()
```

and I assume that `destructor` attribute would mean `dumb_destructor()` would be called during `__libc_csu_fini`, but that's not happening:

```
Breakpoint 1, dumb_destructor () at main.cpp:3
3   void __attribute__ ((destructor)) dumb_destructor(){}
(gdb) bt
#0  dumb_destructor () at main.cpp:3
#1  0x00007ffff7fe242b in _dl_fini () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#2  0x00007ffff7ad4537 in __run_exit_handlers () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff7ad46ee in exit () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#4  0x00007ffff7abd02a in __libc_start_main () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#5  0x000000000040104e in _start ()
```

I sanity checked that `__libc_csu_fini` really isn't doing anything with objdump and it really is a stub:

```
0000000000401190 <__libc_csu_fini>:
  401190:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
  401194:   c3                      ret
```

Why do we call this `_dl_fini`? *What is `_dl_fini`*? Why is it being inconsistent and not calling `__libc_csu_fini`?

Comment: This glibc source code comment seems relevant https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/csu/elf-init.c#L92-L94 , along with various commits pointed to by git blame

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I refer to the most recent glibc version tag as of writing this, which is glibc 2.34 (published in August 2021), and which changed quite a bit of the startup process (I highlight the major differences). Most findings should also apply to other versions and architectures. The ELF dumps in this answer are from an x86-64 system.

---

Before we can look into the destructors, we have to understand what is going on at startup.

### What does actually happen when we run a program?

#### Kernel: Load the program binary and the dynamic linker

I skip some kernel-mode parts here for brevity. We start at a point where our program's ELF file is already mapped into memory according to its [segment ("program header") table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format#Program_header):

```
$ readelf -l a.out

Elf file type is DYN (Shared object file)
Entry point 0x10a0
There are 13 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  PHDR           0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000000040
                 0x00000000000002d8 0x00000000000002d8  R      0x8
  INTERP         0x0000000000000318 0x0000000000000318 0x0000000000000318
                 0x000000000000001c 0x000000000000001c  R      0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000628 0x0000000000000628  R      0x1000
  LOAD           0x0000000000001000 0x0000000000001000 0x0000000000001000
                 0x0000000000000215 0x0000000000000215  R E    0x1000
  LOAD           0x0000000000002000 0x0000000000002000 0x0000000000002000
                 0x00000000000001a0 0x00000000000001a0  R      0x1000
  LOAD           0x0000000000002da8 0x0000000000003da8 0x0000000000003da8
                 0x0000000000000268 0x0000000000000270  RW     0x1000
...(and a few more)
```

Our application is dynamically linked (i.e., the ELF file does not contain all functions it calls), so we have to load all dependencies into the process's virtual address space as well. However, the kernel itself has only limited understanding of the ELF format, and should not make too many assumptions about the user space environment anyway. Thus, ELF specifies a special *interpreter* program, which path can be found in the `INTERP` segment.

On Linux, this usually happens to be the *dynamic linker* `lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`. The kernel subsequently loads that dynamic linker ELF into the same virtual address space as our application and then calls the dynamic linker's entry point (*not* the entry point of our application).

#### Dynamic linker: Load and initialize dependencies

The dynamic linker now reads the `DYNAMIC` segment (*dynamic table*) of our program, which contains information about needed dependencies, symbol tables, relocations and so on:

```
$ readelf -d a.out

Dynamic section at offset 0x2dc8 contains 27 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x000000000000000c (INIT)               0x1000
 0x000000000000000d (FINI)               0x1208
 0x0000000000000019 (INIT_ARRAY)         0x3da8
 0x000000000000001b (INIT_ARRAYSZ)       16 (bytes)
 0x000000000000001a (FINI_ARRAY)         0x3db8
 0x000000000000001c (FINI_ARRAYSZ)       16 (bytes)
 0x000000006ffffef5 (GNU_HASH)           0x3a0
 0x0000000000000005 (STRTAB)             0x470
 0x0000000000000006 (SYMTAB)             0x3c8
 0x000000000000000a (STRSZ)              130 (bytes)
...(and a few more)
```

With that information it starts visiting all `NEEDED` dependencies of our program, recursively. For each dependency, the following steps are executed:

- Map the corresponding ELF file into virtual memory.
- Parse its dynamic table and load dependencies.
- Run [`dl_init`](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/glibc-2.34/elf/dl-init.c#L76), which calls all functions from the `INIT`/`INIT_ARRAY` dynamic table entries (i.e., the library's constructors).

Once the dynamic linker is done and all dependencies are loaded and initialized, it hands over control to our application's entry point ([`_start`](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/glibc-2.34/sysdeps/x86_64/start.S#L57)).

#### Our program: Initialize libc and run constructors

`_start` gets a few arguments, most notably a function pointer to [`_dl_fini`](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/glibc-2.34/elf/dl-fini.c#L30) in *`rdx`*. `_start` then prepares the stack, places some arguments in registers and finally calls [`__libc_start_main`](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/glibc-2.34/csu/libc-start.c#L223).

`__libc_start_main` receives the following arguments:

- A function pointer to `main` (which is the `main` method we wrote)
- `argc`, `argv`
- A function pointer *`init`* (pointing to `__libc_csu_init` before glibc 2.34)
- A function pointer *`fini`* (pointing to `__libc_csu_fini` before glibc 2.34)
- A function pointer *`rtld_fini`* (which equals the *`rdx`* argument of `_start` and thus points to `_dl_fini`)

The function does some initialization of libc, sets up thread local storage and stack canaries, and a lot more. Here we only care for two calls:

- [`__cxa_atexit ((void (*) (void *)) rtld_fini, NULL, NULL);`](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/glibc-2.34/csu/libc-start.c#L344), which registers `_dl_fini` as destructor to run after program exit
- [A call *either*](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/glibc-2.34/csu/libc-start.c#L372) to *`init`* = `__libc_csu_init` (< glibc 2.34) *or* to [`call_init`](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/glibc-2.34/csu/libc-start.c#L125) (>= glibc 2.34)

Both `__libc_csu_init` and `call_init` do basically the same thing: They run all constructors registered in the dynamic table entries `INIT` and `INIT_ARRAY`. However, while `__libc_csu_init` is statically compiled into our program, `call_init` lives in libc and thus in a different memory region. This was [changed](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/commit/035c012e32c11e84d64905efaf55e74f704d3668) after security researchers [found a ROP gadget](https://i.blackhat.com/briefings/asia/2018/asia-18-Marco-return-to-csu-a-new-method-to-bypass-the-64-bit-Linux-ASLR-wp.pdf) in `__libc_csu_init`'s assembly code.

**We thus observe the following backtrace for each constructor:**

- `my_constructor()`
- `__libc_csu_init()` (< glibc 2.34) *or* `call_init()` (>= glibc 2.34)
- `__libc_start_main()`
- `_start()`

After `__libc_start_main` is done, it [transfers control](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/glibc-2.34/sysdeps/generic/libc_start_call_main.h) to our `main` method:

```
_Noreturn static __always_inline void
__libc_start_call_main (int (*main) (int, char **, char ** MAIN_AUXVEC_DECL),
                        int argc, char **argv MAIN_AUXVEC_DECL)
{
  exit (main (argc, argv, __environ MAIN_AUXVEC_PARAM));
}
```

---

We now have seen what happens when an executable is initialized. But what about the end?

### Running finalizers

As we can see in the code snippet above, `exit` runs as soon as `main` returns. So what does `exit` do?

Turns out, it [only transfers control](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/glibc-2.34/stdlib/exit.c#L141) to [`__run_exit_handlers`](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/glibc-2.34/stdlib/exit.c#L38):

```
void
exit (int status)
{
  __run_exit_handlers (status, &__exit_funcs, true, true);
}
```

`__run_exit_handlers` then calls the various functions which have been registered in the `__exit_funcs` list via calls like `__cxa_atexit`. If we now look back at the startup procedure, we see that this list should also contain our `_dl_fini` function, as it was passed as *`rtld_fini`* argument to `_start`/`__libc_start_main`!

[`_dl_fini`](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/glibc-2.34/elf/dl-fini.c#L30) is the finalizer of the dynamic linker, which iterates through all dependencies *and* our executable and runs the destructors from `FINI` and `FINI_ARRAY` for each of them.

**We thus get the following backtrace for each destructor:**

- `my_destructor()`
- `_dl_fini()`
- `__run_exit_handlers()`
- `exit()`
- `__libc_start_main()`
- `_start()`

This answers the "what", but not the "why".

---

### Why is it being inconsistent and not calling `__libc_csu_fini`?

(please take the following with a grain of salt - I could not find sources for the original reasoning, but inferred that from the source code, commit messages and some comments)

I believe that actually the contrary was intended: To be more consistent. The dynamic linker took care of running the constructors of all dependencies, so it should also run their destructors. And as our program is not much different to those dependencies, why not run its destructors as well? Probably that is the reason why `__libc_csu_fini` was [disabled around 17 years ago](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/commit/9dcafc559763e339d4a79580c333127033e39c11#diff-ff3def350ece6004061f2d9b58d4bd16bb8c567baac8b095a4a1f22a55e4b000R89). I am not sure why it wasn't removed completely - probably to keep compatibilty with existing compilers.

With the recent release of glibc 2.34, both the `__libc_csu_init` and `__libc_csu_fini` functions were removed entirely, as their tasks are now done by other parts of the runtime.

#### So why does the dynamic linker not run our program's constructors in `dl_init`?

Well, `dl_init` runs before our app's entry point `_start` - where several important parts of the runtime are not yet available (the initialization is done in `__libc_start_main`). So our constructors would need to be self-contained and avoid calling external functions. As this would pose quite a risk for reliability and security, the constructors are instead executed after all other initialization is done.

Actually, there [*is* support](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/glibc-2.34/elf/dl-init.c#L78) for initialization functions which are executed by `dl_init` - these may be specified via the `PREINIT` and `PREINIT_ARRAY` dynamic table entries, and run before our `_start` function. However, [there does not appear to be a straightforward way to register these with the compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21244313/how-to-append-to-preinit-array-start-on-linux), and it is not recommended for the above reasons anyway.

---

*Note:* Answering this question took a lot of digging into the inner workings of glibc, which turned out to be even more complex than I initially expected. In order to make this a coherent answer, I had to simplify a few things and skip others. If you find anything inaccurate, please feel free to edit or raise this in the comments.

Comment: Related: [Linux x86 Program Start Up
or - How the heck do we get to main()?](http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/debugging/linuxProgramStartup.html) is an older (and longer) write-up from long before glibc 2.34.  It has more details on some thing, but probably less focus on the some other things this answer covers.  And of course doesn't mention the glibc 2.34 changes.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation! But I'm afraid I find the answer to "why does the dynamic linker not run our program's constructors in dl_init?" unsatisfactory, because it doesn't provide justification for why "dl_init runs before our app's entry point _start." I agree fully that constructors ought to run after libc initializes, but why isn't the solution "pass dl_init to __libc_start_main" instead? The way it works now only solves the problem for constructors in the main binary.